# Is there a way to mock a property on a request object

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I have a Javascript REST api endpoint defined using swagger. In my controller, I am logging the IP address from the incoming request.

This is functioning just fine but now I am trying to add Jest tests for coverage and each time I run my test I am getting an error thrown

```
module.exports.execute = async function execute (req, res) {
    try {
        log.info("Start processing request from client IP="+req.connection.remoteAddress);
        ... do some stuff
        log.info("Finished processing request from client IP="+req.connection.remoteAddress);
    } catch(err) {
        log.error("Error caught in Address controller =>" + err.message);
        utils.writeJson(res, err.message, 500);
    }
};
```

When I execute my tests, I am getting Error caught in controller =>Cannot read property 'remoteAddress' of undefined

When I comment out the lines that call req.connection.remoteAddress, all is good and I get coverage but not for those 2 lines.

I am guessing the issue is that the req.connection.remoteAddress is a property and not a function.

Is there a way I can mock the response from this call to return a statis string like 1.1.1.1 ?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you already mocking the `req` and `res` objects you pass when testing? If so, you simply need to add a `connection.remoteAddress` attribute to the `req` object.

Comment: Yes, I am with the following line `const mockReq = _.set({}, 'swagger.params.entity.value', JSON.stringify({
            fail: false
        }));`

Comment: I tried this but still same error `const mockReq = _.set({}, 'swagger.params.entity.value', JSON.stringify({
            fail: false}),'connection.remoteAddress','192.168.1.1');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about the question in the first comment from @Will Alexander, I added this (second line) and now all is good.  Thank you Will

```
let mockReq = _.set({},'swagger.params.entity.value', JSON.stringify({            fail: false}));
mockReq.connection = _.set({},'remoteAddress', '1.1.1.1');
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)